# I want to write a function that retrieves a webpage

Tags: c, linux, libcurl

I'm trying to write a function that returns the html code of a specified URL
here's my code so far:

```
char * getHtml()
{
    struct BufferStruct buffer;
    CURLcode result;
    CURL *myHandle;

    printf("success\n");
    // Passing the function pointer to LC
    curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
    printf("success\n");
     // Passing our BufferStruct to LC
    curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)&buffer);
    curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com");

    result = curl_easy_perform( myHandle );

    curl_easy_cleanup( myHandle );
    return buffer.buffer;
}
```

only the first success string is printed:
success

```
./compile: line 3: 27548 Segmentation fault      ./a.out
```

here's my writememorycallback:

```
static size_t WriteMemoryCallback (void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *data)
{
    size_t realsize = size * nmemb;        
    struct BufferStruct *mem = (struct BufferStruct *) data;

    mem->buffer = realloc(mem->buffer, mem->size + realsize + 1);   
    if (mem->buffer == NULL)
        return 0;

    if (mem->buffer)
    {
        memcpy(&(mem->buffer[ mem->size ]), ptr, realsize);
        mem->size += realsize;
        mem->buffer[ mem->size ] = 0;
    }
    return realsize;
}
```

the same code when embedded into the body of the main function works just fine.

Comment: Please indent the code, I just did it for another post. Install `astyle` for example and just `astyle -A1 mysourcefile.c` will do. And here `struct BufferStruct * mem = (struct BufferStruct *) data;` it can be `struct BufferStruct *mem = data;`! Also, `mem->buffer = realloc(mem->buffer, mem->size + realsize + 1);` what if `mem->buffer` is `NULL` after the `realloc()`? Your program will leak memory!

Comment: Are you sure passing an uninitialized pointer to `curl_easy_setopt` is a good idea? I'm fairly sure you're invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: @szczurcio There is no problem, but it sure has to be initialized before `curl_easy_perform()`.

Comment: added teh following:   buffer.buffer = NULL;
  buffer.size = 0;

and no nothing :(

Comment: @iharob, I'll fix all that once I get the application working

Comment: No, do it as you develop it. Trust me, it will help you spot simple mistakes and it will keep your code pleasant to work with. Honestly, I can't work with messy code, I can't even look at it! عادل انا عربي ايضن، اسمي يعرب. Do you have a debugger? Try stepping trhough the code to see where exactly the segmentation fault occurs.

Comment: nice to meet you يعرب. I've fixed my indentation to something a little more pleasant to read, my debugger just says that getHtml() is where the sigsegv occurs:
#0  0x00007ffff7b983ec in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4
#1  0x00007ffff7ba5499 in curl_easy_setopt () from /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4
#2  0x0000000000400e3a in getHtml ()
#3  0x0000000000400be3 in main ()

Comment: So this is a copy of the getinmemory.c example from curl, but it removed some things that then makes it crash. Lovely. http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html

Comment: initializing teh curl handle fixed everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If only the first string *success* is printed out then something probably went wrong with the first call to the curl function.

The first step you should do is to check every return value of curl functions:

```
CURLcode ok = curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
if( ok != CURLE_OK )
{
    printf( "Error here %d\n" , __LINE__ );
}
```

The real reason this first call to a curl function failed is that `CURL *myHandle` wasn't initialized:

So initialize it:

```
CURL *myHandle= curl_easy_init();
if(!myHandle) { /*handle error ...*/ }
```

And delete it after you are done:

```
curl_easy_cleanup(myHandle);
```

The other problem as already pointed out, is that `struct BufferStruct buffer` isn't initialized, thus realloc in WriteMemoryCallback fails when called with an uninitialized pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You never initialize `buffer`, you should set `buffer.buffer` to `NULL` in order for `realloc()` to work as you expect and `buffer.size` has to be initialized to or your program would invoke undefined behavior.

You should do this in `getHtml()`

```
buffer.buffer = NULL;
buffer.size = 0;
```

before `curl_easy_perform()`.

Also, to use `realloc()` in a safe manner do this

```
void *aux;
aux = realloc(mem->buffer, mem->size + realsize + 1);
if (aux == NULL)
    return 0; // Maybe `free(mem->buffer); mem->buffer = NULL; mem->size = 0;'
mem->buffer = aux;
// Continue, memcpy() and update mem->size
```

Comment: yeah I get the same result, I did modify my code to check if mem->buffer is NULL after the realloc.